# C, тестирование аллокатора

Tags: c, память, тестирование, нагрузочное-тестирование

Пишется некий внутренний распределятор памяти. В принципе быстродействие не так важно, но всё равно хочется потестировать его эффективность и попробовать найти узкие места.

Банальные тести типа "миллион раз выделить/освободить и сравнить с malloc/free" не кажутся осмысленными.

Единственное что пока придумывается - взять какой-нибудь относительно тяжёлую *реальную* вычислительную задачу, которая интенсивно выделяет и освобождает память, и погонять на ней. Что это может быть? Работа с деревьями, что-то ещё? Хочется каких-нибудь реальных примеров, но в голову ничего не лезет.

Или другие варианты?

Comment: я бы взял любую 3д игру (тот же классический дум/квейк) и подсунул ему аллокатор. И посмотрел на разницу. А в динамических играх она обычно ощущается. Но нужно проверить, не используют ли они свои внутренние аллокаторы:).

Comment: @KoVadim, слишком субъективная оценка будет. Хочется точных циферок :)  И изучения данных gprof. Да и не предназначен он для глобальной замены системных аллокаторов - речь идёт о частном  (пока) случае, когда всё распределение идёт в пределах одного предварительно захваченного фрагмента. Допустим, в пределах нескольких мегабайт.

Comment: Тогда нужно делать бенчмарки на Вашей конкретной задаче.

Comment: Так как раз и хочется что-то другое. К тому же её непросто привести к нужному виду, там память дёргается в час по чайной ложке...

Comment: Если память дергается по чайной ложке, тогда не вижу смысла в кастомном аллокаторе и вообще тестировать на "узкие места".

Comment: Ну, "в час" - это образно, на добротный нагрузочный тест не тянет :) А смысл пока теоретический и исследовательский. Может ещё где пригодится, лучше заранее пошуршать. Пока энтузиазм не пропал и другого не навалилось... Техдолги лучше не создавать.

Comment: может просто большой массив выделенных блоков. выделаем случайное кол-во блоков случайного размера. потом освобождаем случайное число блоков. и так в цикле гоняем подольше. кроме времени обращаем внимание на фрагментацию памяти

Comment: В качестве офтопа. Всегда интересовал вопрос. Зачем в программе высвобождать память ?

Comment: @Yaroslav, программа не обязательно должна быть одноразовой. А висеть годами, как, например, какой-нибудь демон, сервис, или модуль ядра. Вот пришёл к ней запрос на какое-то действие, она его выполнила, затратив сколько-то памяти. И не освободила. А потом пришёл ещё запрос, и ещё, и ещё... Да даже на пользовательском уровне: представьте, что вы не закрываете браузер после каждой ссылки, а он не освобождает память, потраченную на показ каждой страницы.

Comment: @Mike, вот как раз такой тест не кажется показательным, я об этом сразу написал в вопросе.

Comment: А почему нет. если в "показательном" тесте размер объектов не фиксирован, а часто отличается (например набор строк текста для текстового редактора) то на сколько это оличается от "случайного"

Comment: @PinkTux . Тогда, если у нас  есть сервер который обрабатывает  запросы . В программе выделяется блок памяти для обработки  запроса. Пришел запрос , положили в выделенный блок памяти, обработали . Пришел следующий запрос, положили в тот же блок  памяти. Зачем высвобождать ?

Comment: @Yaroslav,  задайте вопрос отдельно. Будет интересно - возможно, вы открыли что-то новое :-)

Comment: Если вы не видите разницы при работе вашего приложения, то выбросьте ваш allocator (нет allocator -- нет тех.долга -- самый быстрый с наименьшим кол-вом багов код, очень дешёвый в поддержке -- это код, который не написан -- всегда полезно эту опцию рассмотреть). Если польза от allocator для текущего состояния вашего приложения есть, то для *"А смысл пока теоретический и исследовательский."*, чтобы снизить вероятность сюрпризов при эволюции вашего приложения, подойдёт адаптация тестов из других проектов (думаю многие большие проекты имеют свои allocator, заточенные для разных подзадач).

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, всё уже придумали до нас. Необходимое обнаружилось в [Linux Test Project](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp): утилита [ebizzy](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/tree/master/utils/benchmark/ebizzy-0.3). Хоть она и довольно пожилая (2007 год), всё необходимое там есть:

> ebizzy is designed to generate a workload resembling common web
>   application server workloads.  It is highly threaded, has a large
>   in-memory working set with low locality, and allocates and deallocates
>   memory frequently.  When running most efficiently, it will max out the
>   CPU.

Код внутри неё довольно простой, разобраться что и как она делает можно без проблем. Всё чётко и по делу.

Единственное что пришлось изменить - добавить ключик в `getopt()`, при наличии которого она будет использовать внешний аллокатор вместо системного. Весь diff приводить не буду, он тривиальный, просто пара моментов, если вдруг захочется свой внедрить:

```
static void *
alloc_mem(size_t size)
{
  char *p;
  int err = 0;
  /* mmap мы не тестируем, на этот кусок не обращаем внимания: */
  if (always_mmap) {
    p = mmap((void *) 0, size, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),
       (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS), -1, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED)
      err = 1;
  } else {
    /* ВОТ ОНО: */
    p = use_external_alloc ? external_alloc(size) : malloc(size);
```

И сюда:

```
static void
free_mem(void *p, size_t size)
{
  if (always_mmap)
    munmap(p, size);
  else
    /* ЕЩЁ ОНО: */
    use_external_alloc ? external_free(p) : free(p);
}
```

Теперь прогоняем тесты. Везде добавляем ключ `-t 1` (работаем в 1 потоке). Стандарный запуск с системным аллокатором, размер блоков памяти фиксирован. По умолчанию зависит от железа/ОС и в данном случае составляет 524288 байт, то есть 512 Kb.

```
$ ./ebizzy -t 1
4484 records/s
real 10.00 s
user  3.47 s
sys   7.17 s
```

Запуск с внешним аллокатором:

```
$ ./ebizzy -k -t 1
16553 records/s
real 10.00 s
user 10.45 s
sys   0.09 s
```

То же самое, но вместо стандартных блоков памяти генерим блоки случайных размеров, до 512 Kb:

```
$ ./ebizzy -R -t 1
75828 records/s
real 10.00 s
user  8.98 s
sys   2.28 s

$ ./ebizzy -R -k -t 1
89585 records/s
real 10.00 s
user 11.20 s
sys   0.07 s
```

Как видим, значения `user+sys` в обеих парах практически совпадают. Но скорость обработки в первом случае отличается почти в 4 раза! В случае блоков случайного размера разница уже не такая, но она есть, и стабильно сохраняется при большом количестве запусков. Но радоваться рано, при уменьшении размеров блоков до 1 Kb системный аллокатор вырывается вперёд (а на многих задачах это куда более частая ситуация):

```
./ebizzy -s 1024 -t 1
5394867 records/s
real 10.00 s
user 11.84 s
sys   0.22 s

./ebizzy -s 1024 -k -t 1
4953828 records/s
real 10.00 s
user 11.89 s
sys   0.13 s
```

В общем, можно гонять по-разному, анализировать, делать выводы. Запускать gprof/gcov и думать дальше. Но главное что технология освоена, и утилитка вполне себя оправдывает.